# HTTP Live Streaming duration less than 10 seconds allowed?

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

We're trying to do low latency video on iOS while complying with Apple's HLS guidelines for video over cellular. From a technical perspective we can set our EXT-X-TARGETDURATION: to N seconds where N is less than 10 (think 2 or 3 seconds).

Practically, is this allowed? Does anyone have experiencing with an app getting approved when using HLS segments of 5 seconds or fewer? I have heard anecdotal evidence that this is not allowed.

Regarding Apple's rules, nothing I've seen has a restriction on segment minimums. However, there is a technical note that states:

"We strongly recommend a 10 second target duration."

The question is whether that recommendation is effectively an unstated rule.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html

One further note - Apple provides a "Media Stream Validator Tool" which does not report errors on streams with target durations of 2 or 3 seconds. That further suggests the stream duration is "valid".

Thank you for any experience/thoughts. Also, if you know of any approved apps that you believe are using HLS segments of 5 seconds or fewer, that would also be helpful since I can check to see if they are indeed using shorter duration and use that as a comp for Apple's approval.